# Multiple standalone neo4j instances on a single machine

Tags: neo4j

I was wondering if I could run multiple standalone instances of neo4j on a single machine. I understand that I could configure multiple instances as HA cluster ([here](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/ha-setup-tutorial.html#ha-local-cluster)), but that is not my intention, I only need two totally different and independent instances of neo4j on my machine (Which is a Mac OSX if that makes a difference). This is only for my dev testing and I tried having two separate directories with different `data/` and setting two different ports for them, but only one runs properly.

I would appreciate any help coming my way. Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The most easy way is to unpack the neo4j installation into two different locations. In one of the locations you need to change the port settings in `conf/neo4j-server.properties` and, if neo4j-shell is enabled  `conf/neo4j.properties` as well.

Also consider to set `dbms.pagecache.memory` to a reasonable value. By default each instance will eat up up to 75 % of RAM minus heap space - which is too much when running multiple instance on one box.

Based on @mepla's findings: the https port in `neo4j-server.properties` needs to be changed as well.

Comment: This is exactly what I have done, I setup one instance to run on port 7477 with `dbms.pagecache.memory=2g` and set another instance to run on 7478 with the same pagecache.memory, the first one runs correctly, the second one upon `bin/neo4j start` says Neo4j Server may have failed to start, please check the logs. And the log says that the port is already in use and changing that to anything else still generates this error.

Comment: I guess that the shell connection points to the same port in both instances. See config option `remote_shell_port` http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/shell-starting.html#config_remote_shell_port. In case you're using enterprise edition also check for the port(s) for online backup and/or clustering. If trouble persists, grab a snippet from `messages.log` and `neo4j.0.0.log`

Comment: Well, I have not enabled shell on any of these two, and it is disabled by default I believe (http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/shell-starting.html).

Comment: I have found out that the HTTPS port was the source of conflict. Thank you very much for your help and please update your answer with the check for HTTPS too so I can accept it as answer. thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can also run individual docker images which point to different data directories,

see: http://neo4j.com/developer/docker

Comment: Thanks, It was cool to know about that but I needed a solution to to solve it using Neo4j config files.

Comment: Also need to expose different ports for each container?

Answer (score 5):

You can use Ineo:

https://github.com/cohesivestack/ineo

> A simple but useful Neo4j instance manager

Answer (score 3):

this github repository ([Multiple-Instances-Neo4j-Manager](https://github.com/Alirezahr75/Multiple-Instances-Neo4j-Manager)) provides neo4j manager to deal with multiple standalone instances on a single machine.